# QuickBooks PHP API Creating Invoice, mail not working

Tags: php, api, quickbooks

have a problem with QB PHP api, when creating Invoices I can not set the email address. Here is the code;

```
$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();
$Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();
$Invoice->setDocNumber($sale->ID);
$Invoice->setDueDate($sale->duedate);
$Invoice->setCustomerRef($customer->qbID);
$Invoice->setBillEmail("at@at.com");
```

setBillEmail should work, but can not understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuickBooks PHP libs exactly mirror the Intuit schema. That means that when you see a *nested object* in the schema like this:

```
 "BillEmail": {
     "Address": "Familiystore@intuit.com"
 },
```

You need a nested object in your PHP code too:

```
$BillEmail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillEmail();
$BillEmail->setAddress('you@youremail.com');
$Invoice->setBillEmail($BillEmail);
```

Comment: Ouu now I have noticed, after long work I was seeing it it like this.

"BillEmail":  "Address": "Familiystore@intuit.com" ,

My bad..